# Sequelize: Deep population association join query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a three tables as shown in this diagram https://dbdiagram.io/d/602fa54dfcdcb6230b2095e5

I would like to get my result as below json.

```
"data": [{
    "products": {
        "id": 12,
        "product_catalog_id": 1,
        "product_catalog": {
            "id": 1,
            "full_name": "Test"
        }
        "product_images": {
            "id": 11,
            "product_catalog_id": 1
        }
    }
}]
```

For that I have applied like below association rules of sequelize ORM

```
ProductModel.belongsTo(ProductCatalogModel, {foreignKey: 'product_catalog_id', targetKey: 'id', as : 'products' })
ProductImagesModel.belongsToMany(ProductCatalogModel , {through: ProductModel, foreignKey: 'product_catalog_id', targetKey: 'id', as :'product_images' });
ProductCatalogModel.belongsToMany(ProductImagesModel , {through: ProductModel, foreignKey: 'product_catalog_id', targetKey: 'id', as :'product_images' });
```

To find the result have applied below query.

```
var associations: Array<FindOptions | any> = [];
associations.push({
    model: ProductModel,
    as: 'products',
    include: [{
        model: ProductImagesModel,
        as: 'product_images,
    }]
})
var execute = await this.model.findAll()
return execute;
```

But instead of mapping the `productImages` model with `productCatalog` model it is going to map it with `products` table model.

I have also tries with the `sequelize.literal` into ProductImagesModel but that is throwing me an error like
`"Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object."`

```
associations.push({
    model: ProductModel,
    as: 'products',
    include: [{
        // model: ProductImagesModel,
        // as: 'product_images,
        include: [sequelize.literal(`(
            SELECT id, product_catalog_id FROM product_images AS product_images 
            WHERE product_images.product_catalog_id IN (1)
        )`)]
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler than you are making it. Try following this pattern:

```js
const pugs = await Pug.findAll({ include: [{ model: Owner }] })
```

This should result in a list of pugs with an `owner` attribute with the owner attributes nested inside.

Comment: Yes that is true, but I don't want that model as nested.

Comment: How about `const user = await User.findByPk(request.userId)` then `const userTasks = await user.getTasks()` — https://ajbraus.github.io/sequelize-it/#/?id=defining-association